# QRCode Scanner Not Working in iOS 11, only showing camera preview

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, swift4, avcapture

It only shows output of camera, but nothing is happning. I don't know what's the problem.

My code is:

```
    class QRScannerController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

        var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
        var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
        var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?
let supportedCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]
        var resultString = ""



 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else {return}

        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
            captureSession?.addInput(input)
           let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes

            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

          captureSession?.startRunning()

            qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

            if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
                self.view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
                self.view.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView)
            }

             captureSession?.startRunning()

        } catch {
            // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }
```

**Delegate:**

```
// MARK: - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate Methods

    func metadataOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
            //messageLabel.text = "No QR/barcode is detected"
            print("No QR/barcode is detected")
            return
        }

        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {

            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {


                print(metadataObj.stringValue as Any)
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to debug by putting breakpoints, but neither of the breakpoints get fired in the delegate method.

Does anybody know why is this happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your delegate method is wrong. Replace

```
func metadataOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

with

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

Comment: should be marked as duplicate you already have enough reputation to do it

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware that this was a duplicate (not an *exact* duplicate though).

Comment: thanks @the4kman...  !!!

Comment: Refer link https://cocoapods.org/pods/MGPBarcodeScanner